# Binomial expansion question of complex sine

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

How to show that the binomial expansion of $$\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^{2n+1}$$ equals
$$\sin ^{2n+1}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k+n}{{2n+1}\choose{k}}\frac{\sin ((2n-2k+1))x}{2^{2n}}$$
Please help! Sorry for asking such a dumb question!

Comment: I think this is just a matter of expanding by the binomial theorem, rearranging the terms in pairs, and using the definition of sine. I suggest you give it a try and ask again if necessary, editing the question to show your working and indicating where you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the upper bound of the summation should be $2n +1$ not $n$, and it should be $2^{2n + 1}$ not $2^{2n}$. You want to use the binomial theorem
$$(x + y)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k } x^k y^{n - k}$$
This tells us
$$\left( e^{ix} - e^{-ix} \right)^{2n + 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{2n + 1} {2n + 1 \choose k} e^{i(2n + 1 - k)x} \left(-e^{-ix} \right)^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{2n + 1} { 2n + 1 \choose k} (-1)^ke^{(2n - 2k + 1)ix} \\
= \sum_{k = 0}^{2n + 1} { 2n + 1 \choose k} (-1)^k \cos{ \left((2n -2k+1)x\right) } + i \sum_{k = 0}^{2n + 1} { 2n + 1 \choose k} (-1)^k \sin{ \left((2n -2k+1)x\right) }$$
See that both sums are real. This means that the sum with the sines is the imaginary part of $\left( e^{ix} - e^{-ix} \right)^{2n + 1}$. Then because the left hand side of
$$
\sin^{2n + 1} x = \left( \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i} \right)^{2n + 1} = \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n + 1} i} \left( e^{ix} - e^{-ix} \right)^{2n + 1}
$$
is purely real, we only want the imaginary part of $\left(e^{ix} - e^{-ix} \right)^{2n + 1}$ so that the right hand side is purely real (this also tells us that the sum with the cosines must be 0). Substituting the sum with the sines gives the answer.
$$
\sin^{2n + 1} x = \frac{1}{2^{2n + 1}}\sum_{k = 0}^{2n + 1} (-1)^{n + k} { 2n + 1 \choose k }  \sin{ \left((2n -2k+1)x\right) }
$$

Edit: It seems that the upper bound being $n$ and it being $2^{2n}$ is actually correct, as the expression above simplifies because the terms in the sum are equal when $k = n + i$ and $k = n - (i - 1)$

We will split the sum as:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{2n + 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^n + \sum_{k = n + 1}^{2n + 1}$$
We will manipulate the second sum $\sum_{k = n + 1}^{2n + 1}$ as follows by substituting $k = j + (n + 1)$ so that the sum starts at $j = 0$ and ends at $j = n$
$$
\sum_{k = n + 1}^{2n + 1} = \sum_{j = 0}^{n} (-1)^{n + j + (n + 1)} { 2n + 1 \choose j + n + 1 }  \sin{ \left((2n - 2(j + n + 1) +1)x\right) } \\
= \sum_{j = 0}^{n} (-1)^{j + 1} { 2n + 1 \choose j + n + 1 }  \sin{ \left(-2j - 1)x\right) }
$$
And now we substitute $j = n - k$ so the sum starts at $k = n$ and ends at $k = 0$. That is, we are changing the order of summation to be backwards so we have
$$
\sum_{j = 0}^{n} (-1)^{j + 1} { 2n + 1 \choose j + n + 1 }  \sin{ \left(\left(-2j - 1\right)x\right) } = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^{n - k + 1} { 2n + 1 \choose 2n - k + 1 }  \sin{ \left( (-2n + 2k - 1)x\right) } \\
= \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^{n + k} { 2n + 1 \choose k }  \sin{ \left( (2n - 2k + 1)x\right) }
$$
where in the last step we used the oddness of $\sin$ and ${ n \choose k} = { n \choose n - k}$ for any positive integers $k \le n$. This is the same as the $\sum_{k = 0}^n$ sum from before so we have
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{2n + 1} = 2 \sum_{k = 0}^n
$$
The two in the front will cancel reduce the $2^{2n + 1}$ to $2^{2n}$ so we'll have

$$
\sin^{2n + 1} x = \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n} (-1)^{n + k} { 2n + 1 \choose k }  \sin{ \left((2n -2k+1)x\right) }
$$

Comment: When we have expanded $$(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{2n+1}$$ into cos and isin , we need to take the imaginary part, then you just can multiply both sides with $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{2n+1}}$ for it to be equal to $\sin x$ and to take real part, right? Also, $i^{2n}$ which you pulled out is (-1)^{n}, right?

Comment: The imaginary part of $(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})^{2n + 1}$ is the sum of sines without the $\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n + 1}}$ factor.  If you only take imaginary parts and then bring the factor (I don't know why you'd take real part now, as you have a real number on both sides at this point), you've only shown that the sum with the factor is the imaginary part of $(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})^{2n + 1}$ multiplied by the factor. Yes, the $i^{2n}$ is the $(-1)^n$.

Comment: The imaginary part of $(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{2n+1})$ is the part with sine. Multiplying both sides with $\frac{(-1)^{n})}{2^{2n+1}i}$ we get $$\sin ^{2n+1}(x)=\frac{1}{i}\cdot{\cos x}+\sin x $$ part. Since sin on the left side is real, cos part  must be zero and it equals the sum we got. Right?

Comment: I assume you're using $\cos$ and $\sin$ in your right side expression as shorthand for the summations involving them. In that case, yes that's right, the summation with the cosines is 0, and we are left with just the summation with the sines which is the desired result.

Comment: It can also be proved expanding $$\left(\frac{e^{ix}}{2i} -\frac{1}{2ie^{xi}}\right)^{2n+1}$$ into a binomial series, just wanted to say, tried it and it worked. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Why does the sum at the last start from k=1 in your expression, should it be k=0? 
Also , how can we make it go to n. Also, how to make the factor $\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$ in the denominator?

Comment: Yes, the $k = 1$ is a typo, should be $k = 0$. I've eddited the answer to go through all the substitutions to do to get the sum to end at $n$. In esscence, in the sum from $k = 0$ to $k = 2n + 1$, the first term is the same as the last, the second is the same as the second last, the third the same as the third last, and so on. So each of the terms from $k = 0$ upto $k =n $ appear twice, so we can simply ignore the duplicates from $n + 1$ to $2n + 1$ and bring a 2 in the front

Comment: One thing i want to bring up, while  bringing the - in the front from the sine , you didnt change the sign of the 1, it should be $\sin ((2n-2k+1)x)$ also, in that part we had $(-1)^{n-k+1}$ and in the next $(-1)^{n+k}$ the one minus was gone because of the sine, but is $(-1)^{n+k}=(-1)^{n-k}$ just asking

Comment: I fixed the sign of the 1 in the sine. Yes, $(-1)^{n + k} = (-1)^{n - k}$ because $(-1)^k = \frac{1}{(-1)^k} = (-1)^{-k}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ since $\pm 1$ are their own multiplicative inverses

Comment: If it were, 2n instead of 2n+1, we'd have the sum with cosines, right? The imaginary part would be with the sines. The cosine part would be of the form $$\cos ((2n-2k)x)$$ right?